# How to Install Rack Tables in windows 7

Tags: php, xampp

How can i Install Rack Tables in windows 7. Here is the link where i downloaded the Rack Tables `http://racktables.org/` .. I want to know how can i install this system. (Rack Tables is a rack inventory). Im using xampp but whenever i try to install it im getting this error.

**RackTables installation: step 3 of 7**

The `C:\xampp\htdocs\racktables\RackTables-0.20.7\wwwroot\inc/secret.php` file is not writable by web-server. Make sure it is.The following commands should suffice:
touch `'C:\xampp\htdocs\racktables\RackTables-0.20.7\wwwroot\inc/secret.php'; chmod 666 'C:\xampp\htdocs\racktables\RackTables-0.20.7\wwwroot\inc/secret.php'`
Fedora Linux with SELinux may require this file to be owned by specific user (apache) and/or executing `"setenforce 0"` for the time of installation. SELinux may be turned back on with `"setenforce 1"` command.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the file 'secret.php' exists in that folder. If not, just copy past a other .php file and make it empty.
And don't forget to change the windows properties of the file (check off read only).

Answer (score 0):

I just installed on Windows using WAMP.  I had to literally set the file permissions on secret.php to read-only for all users (including System) to get by that screen.